# How to reduce the spacing between link groups in Fabric UI

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

How do I change the spacing between 2 nav groups within a Nav element. I have the following element:

```
  <Nav
    groups={[
      {
        links: [
          {
            key: "profile",
            name: "View Profile",
            url: "/account"
          },
          {
            key: "manageCompanies",
            name: "Manage Companies",
            url: "/manageCompanies"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Sale",
        links: [
          {
            key: "Invoice",
            name: "Invoice",
            url: "/invoice"
          },
          {
            key: "Quotation",
            name: "Quotation",
            url: "/quotation"
          },
          {
            key: "Delivery Challan",
            name: "Delivery Challan",
            url: "/deliveryChallan"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Purchase",
        links: [
          {
            key: "Purchase Order",
            name: "Purchase Order",
            url: "/purchaseOrder"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]}
  />
```

I'm getting the following output:

[image: Output]

How do I remove the empty space between each link group? I've tried `styles` prop, but I'm not able to get rid of the extra space.

Comment: Not familiar with this UI library, but aren't there CSS classes that you can override? I'd guess you can find them pretty easily with the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following styles prop:

```
styles={{
   groupContent: {
       marginBottom: "5px" 
   } 
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a class called `ms-Nav-groupContent` on the nav groups with a `margin-bottom` of 40px. You can override that as long as your CSS is coming after the default styles. Example [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/NWWEmvd).

If you don't want the changes to be globally applied to all nav groups, you can apply a `className` directly to the `Nav` component, and then use the CSS descendant combinator to select only the groups within that Nav, e.g.:

```
.my-class .ms-Nav-groupContent {
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```